# Is there a way to share an in-memory object between multiple websites?

Tags: asp.net, caching, memory, share

We have about 70 sites on our server that use same application (with different Application Pools) and they use for example a shared skin file.
So is there a way to load this file to memory and share for all applications?
what I mean is to sharing cache in multiple websites to decrease pressure on server.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Dwefy. But if you need to share dynamic content in memory have a look at [memcached](http://memcached.org/)

Comment: Also I found a microsoft solution Named "Velocity": http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B24C3708-EEFF-4055-A867-19B5851E7CD2

Answer (score 4):

May be I'm not answering your question directly, but you problem has better solution. The best place for CSS, images, static content is either CDN (content delivery network) or standalone server.

**At first** it improves time of page loading (since per browser convention there only 2 opened threads to single domain). So placing onto standalone server allows browser simultaneously load content from you server and CDN.

**At second** it solves your problem since application doesn't spent time to dispatch requests of static data

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use a shared cache such as memcached then no, there's no way to do this. Even using a shared cache you're still going to be creating temporary objects in each site when you retrieve the item from the cache.

Best to store this somewhere on disk and just share the file.